# TypeScript: Type of the current class as a type variable

Tags: generics, typescript

I want to declare a function in TypeScript that returns the type of the current instance's type, e.g. in a fluent API that returns `this`.

Is there a type variable for "this type"? (I would rather not use the ugly Java way of `X<T extends X<T>>`.)

Comment: I am not sure you can. Perhaps the function can return <any> and in the return statement you can return the desired object, then cast it in the code that consumes the function? Kind of ugly, I know.

Comment: Before doing this, consider how it breaks abstraction: you're asking for an interface to advertise the specific implementation it returns, rather than the contract(/interface) that implementation conforms to. That use would be dangerous, although I imagine there are legitimate cases where this could come in handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a way to do this yet in TypeScript. See issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/285 for voting/discussion.

Answer (score 6):

A fluent interface implementation is now possible:

```
class FluentInterface {
    aMethod(): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you want but for my use case, [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53132773/4834117) was good enough:

```
export class Component{
  init(config?: { [field in keyof this]?: this[field] }) {
    Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}
```