# typescript: reference current class type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to reference current class type in type signature? so that I can do something like this:

```
 export class Component{
  constructor(config?: { [field in keyof self]: any }) {
      Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}
```

the idea is to pass a configuration object that would consist of current class keys.

I could go with interfaces but then I need to type same portion of code twise (in interface and in implementing class)

Another way would be to use generics. Something like this:

```
export class Component<T>{
  init(config?: { [field in keyof T]?: any }) {
    Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}

class TestComponent extends Component<TestComponent>{
  foo: number
}
const component = new TestComponent().init({ foo: 11 })
```

But having code like `class TestComponent extends Component<TestComponent>` makes me to search for better ways...

Comment: Isn't it allowed to write ‘keyof Component‘? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You can, but not in the constructor, you can use `this` as a type. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, wow, cool. This should be an answer. Having `this` not in constructor is completely fine for me. This is event better to make such kind of things somewhere in `init` function, since constructor runs before default values are set up.

Comment: @SET just added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reference the current class using [polymorphic `this` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910)

```
export class Component{
  init(config?: { [field in keyof this]?: this[field] }) {
    Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}

class TestComponent extends Component{
  foo: number
}
const component = new TestComponent().init({ foo: 11 })
const component2 = new TestComponent().init({ foo: "11" }) // err
```

You can't however use `this` as a type in the constructor

```
export class Component{
  constructor(config?: { [field in keyof this]?: this[field] }) { // error
    Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}
```

Comment: worse to mention than one should not even want to do such kind of things in constructor, because default values that class may have, would be populated AFTER constructor execution and, such, would overwrite assignment from config object.

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't this just work?

```
export class Component {
  test = 123;

  constructor(config?: { [field in keyof Component]: any }) {
      Object.assign(this, config)
  }
}


new Component({ test: 123 }) // valid
new Component({ test1: 123 }) // invalid
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Component%7B%0D%0A%20%20test%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(config%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5Bfield%20in%20keyof%20Component%5D%3A%20any%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20config)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Component(%7B%20test%3A%20123%20%7D))

Even shorter would be simple (thanks to duck typing)

```
constructor(config?: Component) {
```

Maybe not really expressing what you want to say / not strict enough, but works.

Even the following is valid

```
constructor(config = <Component>{}) {
```

which directly gives you an empty object as the initial value.

Source: abusing this since TypeScript v1.

Comment: In future, I want hundreds of different components which extends basic `Component` so I should refer to current class, some kind of `this`, not to basic `Component`

Comment: what does it change?  `export class ChildComponent extends Component { constructor(config?: ChildComponent ) { super(config); }}`

Comment: It should work, but going this way, I have to redefine constructor every time in each inherited class. Accepted answer show better solution.

Comment: Why do you need to redefine constructor? I do not see any problem anyway. Please post what is not working with this solution

Comment: it is working but if you will have some classes that will inherit from `Component` and if you would need to have their properties to be assignable withing config object, then you have to redefine constructor in each such class as you showed previously in example with `ChildComponent` class.

Comment: You redefined ChildComponent's constructor to change config type, otherwise it would inherit from Component class and in `new ChildComponent(config)` you will be able to only assign properties that exist in `Component`, but you will not be able to set up new properties that was added in this new inherited `ChildComponent` class